# RegEx: Split into lines an remove characters

Tags: regex, split, character

Using RegEx I'd like to split text into multiple lines and remove special characters.

Sample

```
{"Value1"};{"Value2"};{"Value3"}
```

Should result in:

```
Value1
Value2
Value3
```

I've tried a few things like using:

```
(\b[^\.;]+\b)
```

and

```
\{"(.*?)\"}
```

But I can't seem to combine to two to get it working.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep), I can do what you need:

```
$ grep -oP '\w+' file
```

### Output

```
Value1
Value2
Value3
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use grep. :(

Comment: Is 'perl' available ? Which tools are available ?

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the language you are using. There are several dialects of regex depending on language. Here is a solution, assuming JavaScript:

```js
var str = '{"Value1"};{"Value2"};{"Value3"}';
console.log('str: ' + str);
var result = str.replace(/\{"([^"]*)"\};?/g, '$1\n');
console.log('result:\n' + result);
```

Output:

```
str: {"Value1"};{"Value2"};{"Value3"}
result:
Value1
Value2
Value3
```